# Angular life cycle:- added extra row to angular-material-calendar which I always need to show

Tags: angular

I have a list of calendars in arrays which I am showing on ngOnInit. I am adding extra empty row to angular material calendar. The code for it is below. I am able to add extra row on load. But on click when I add and minus the calendars then I don't see any extra row.
[image: extra row added]

I called ngAfterViewInit on ngOnChanges and tried same code under it also. But its keep on adding rows on click.

I called ngAfterViewInit under the function which adds and minus the calendar from the list but its not doing anything. 
See below image, empty cell row gone on change from the list of calendars
[image]

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.calendars.forEach(calendarEl => {
      const tbody: HTMLElement = calendarEl.nativeElement.querySelector('tbody');
      const tr = (document.createElement('tr') as HTMLTableRowElement);
      tr.className = "date-class"
      for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
      }
      tbody.appendChild(tr);
    })
```

Comment: You should let angular handle creation of DOM elements instead of using vanilla JS DOM manipulation.  

I will assume you mean Angular Material Datepicker element.  

If so, try accessing your date picker element via ViewChild, then checking if you are able to add a row ( or more days most likely. ) via listener / handler.  Not exactly sure what you want to accomplish by adding more rows however..

Comment: I needed to add empty row for UX designing purpose